# Algorithm for ordered curves clustering

Tags: r, clustering, survival, multiple-comparisons

I am looking for some statistical solution to the problem of testing
the similarity of curves. I am working with multiply time series (sort
of survival curves). The curves are calculated as a separate curves
for different values of a categorized continuous variable. For
example:

[image]

I want to test which of the curves are equal and can be combined in
one curve. I know that there are some r packages that use distance
measure to cluster curves, such as tsclust.

What i need is an algorithm that takes into account that only curves
form adjacent intervals of a class variables can be matched. It needs
to be automatic as i have many curves and many class variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar problem with pharmacokinetics curves, I used the standard k-means algorithm. I used it in an automatic way for analyse several datasets, and it worked very well. Each curve is an observation and the variables are the values in each time point (50 variables in this plot)

Comment: Thank you! In this way I can use many different standard clustering
algorithms and treat each curve as one observation. I wonder how did
you provide for specific clustering order. What if the levels of
curves for subsequent classes do not follow the order?

Comment: I don't see this is a problem. Survival curves of two subsequent classes can be crossed (this is a normal situation in survival analysis). The clustering will detect these 2 curves are near or far, but if they are near, for me it is not very important what it is down or up. The clustering summarizes what is the general situation

Answer (score 0):

On such *small* data, **hierarchical clustering** is your best choice.

The bigger challenge is how to preprocess your data to account for different factors (such as group size) that you do not want to take into account.